# OOP Generic Deck/Card implementation in Java

Tags: java, generics, playing-cards

I decided to give this another go. Last attempt can be found [**here**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162342/oop-design-of-a-generic-deck-of-cards)

This time around I tried my best to make this as generic as possible. The goal is to make this usable for any types of cards, not just traditional card-games.

**AbstractOperation.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


public abstract class AbstractCardOperation<T extends Card> implements Receivable<T>, Sendable<T>  {
    protected List<T> cards;

    public AbstractCardOperation() {
        this.cards = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public AbstractCardOperation(List<T> cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    public AbstractCardOperation(List<T> list, int size) {
        cards = IntStream.range(0, size)
                .mapToObj(i -> list)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> removeCards(int numberOfCards) {
        return IntStream.range(0, numberOfCards)
                .mapToObj(i -> cards.remove(i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public T removeCard() {
        if (cards.size() < 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Deck is empty");
        }
        return cards.remove(0);
    }

    @Override
    public T removeCard(int index) {
        if (cards.size() - 1 < index) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Index passed in is > size of deck-1");
        }
        return cards.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCards(List<T> cards) {
        this.cards.addAll(cards);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCard(T card) {
        cards.add(card);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return cards.toString();
    }
}
```

I know this has no `abstract` methods, and thus shouldn't be `abstract`, but it represent a lot of common functionality between `Hand` and `Deck`, and I don't want this to be instantiable. If I made an interface of this, I would have to implement all those functions twice.

**Card.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;


public interface Card<T>  {
    boolean isConsecutive(T other);
    boolean isEqual(T other);
    String toString();
}
```

**Deck.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;


public interface Deck<T extends Card> {
    void shuffle();
    void sort(Comparator<T> sort);
    void addCardToPlayer(List<? super T> hand);
}
```

**Hand.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.List;


public interface Hand<T extends Card> {
   int calculate();
   void addCardToDeck(int index, List<? super T> deck);
   boolean isEqual(List<T> other);
   String toString();
}
```

**Receivable.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.List;


interface Receivable<T extends Card> {
    void addCards(List<T> cards);
    void addCard(T card);
}
```

**Sendable.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.List;


interface Sendable<T extends Card> {
    List<T> removeCards(int numberOfCards);
    T removeCard();
    T removeCard(int index);
}
```

Here is a package with some classes where I implement the interfaces:

**BlackjackCard.java**

```
package com.tn.test;

import com.tn.deck.Card;


public class BlackjackCard implements Card<BlackjackCard> {
    private Suit suit;
    private Rank rank;

    public BlackjackCard(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConsecutive(BlackjackCard other) {
        return Math.abs(rank.getValue() - other.rank.getValue()) == 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEqual(BlackjackCard other) {
        return suit.equals(other.suit) && rank.equals(other.rank);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return suit.getIcon() + "" + rank.getName() + " ";
    }
}
```

**BlackjackDeck.java**

```
package com.tn.test;

import com.tn.deck.AbstractCardOperation;
import com.tn.deck.Card;
import com.tn.deck.Deck;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;


public class BlackjackDeck extends AbstractCardOperation<BlackjackCard> implements Deck<BlackjackCard> {

    public BlackjackDeck(List<BlackjackCard> deck) {
        super(deck);
    }

    public BlackjackDeck(List<BlackjackCard> deck, int numberOfDecks) {
        super(deck, numberOfDecks);
    }

    public List<BlackjackCard> getDeck() {
        return cards;
    }

    @Override
    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
    }

    @Override
    public void sort(Comparator<BlackjackCard> sortable) {
        cards.sort(sortable);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCardToPlayer(List<? super BlackjackCard> hand) {
        hand.add(cards.remove(0));
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T extends Card> void print(Deck<T>... decks) {
        Arrays.stream(decks).forEach(deck -> System.out.println(deck.toString()));
    }
}
```

**Player.java**

```
package com.tn.test;

import java.util.List;


public class Player {
    private PlayerHand hand;

    public Player(PlayerHand hand) {
        this.hand = hand;
    }

    public List<BlackjackCard> getHand() {
        return hand.getHand();
    }

    public void addCardToDeck(int index, List<? super BlackjackCard> deck) {
        hand.addCardToDeck(index, deck);
    }

    public boolean compareHand(Player other) {
        return hand.isEqual(other.hand.getHand());
    }

    public String toString() {
        return hand.toString();
    }
}
```

**PlayerHand.java**

```
package com.tn.test;

import com.tn.deck.AbstractCardOperation;
import com.tn.deck.Hand;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class PlayerHand extends AbstractCardOperation<BlackjackCard> implements Hand<BlackjackCard> {

    public PlayerHand(List<BlackjackCard> hand) {
        super(hand);
    }

    List<BlackjackCard> getHand() {
        return cards;
    }

    @Override
    public int calculate() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCardToDeck(int index, List<? super BlackjackCard> deck) {
        deck.add(cards.remove(index));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEqual(List<BlackjackCard> other) {
        return !Collections.disjoint(cards, other);
    }
}
```

**Rank.java**

```
package com.tn.test;


public enum Rank {
    TWO("2", 2), THREE("3", 3), FOUR("4", 4), FIVE("5", 5),
    SIX("6", 6), SEVEN("7", 7), EIGHT("8", 8), NINE("9", 9), TEN("10", 10),
    JACK("J", 10), QUEEN("Q", 10), KING("K", 10), ACE("A", 11);

    private final String name;
    private final int value;

    Rank(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Suit.java**

```
package com.tn.test;


public enum Suit {
    SPADE("\u2660"),
    HEART("\u2665"),
    DIAMOND("\u2666"),
    CLUB("\u2663");

    private final String icon;

    Suit(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
}
```

And lastly, my Main where I instantiate some of the classes, and test a few methods.

Yes - this should have been unit-tests, and I will implement that as well.

**Main.java**

```
import com.tn.test.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BlackjackCard> blackjackCards = Arrays.stream(Suit.values())
                .flatMap(suit -> Arrays.stream(Rank.values()).map(rank -> new BlackjackCard(suit, rank)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        BlackjackDeck deck = new BlackjackDeck(blackjackCards);
        deck.shuffle();

        Player[] players = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 2)
                .mapToObj(player -> new Player(new PlayerHand(deck.removeCards(5))))
                .toArray(Player[]::new);

        Arrays.stream(players).forEach(player -> System.out.println(player.toString()));

        deck.sort(Comparator
                .comparing(BlackjackCard::getRank)
                .thenComparing(BlackjackCard::getSuit));

        BlackjackDeck.print(deck);


        deck.addCardToPlayer(players[0].getHand());
        System.out.println(players[0].toString());
        players[0].addCardToDeck(4, deck.getDeck());
        System.out.println(players[0].toString());

        BlackjackDeck.print(deck);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `Hand.isEqual(List<T> other)`. Shouldn't the argument be a `Hand` as well and isn't overriding `Object.equals` sufficient?

Comment: @KarlRichter yeah - you're right. But I do want it in the interface to ensure that it will be implemented.

Comment: This is very high quality code. Every part you introduced and I found was expected to be found by me. And every part I looked at had the semantic and the implementation I expected. There are no surprises and no complicated micromanagement. Everythings has its place where it belongs to.

Comment: @oopexpert thank you very much :) Only thing I don't like is that Player inherits from the AbtractClass. In my mind that is not a IS-A relationship.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going into details here but I hope this is still helpful:

- I don't see the need for the `Player` class as it only forwards to the `PlayerHand`
- `Receivable` and `Sendable` are not used
- `Player.compareHand` should be named `isEqual` for consistency
- I personally prefer having null checks in equals methods to ensure nothing breaks if `null` is passed as argument
- `AbstractOperation.removeCards`: It might look more elegant the way you have implemented it but creating a new ArrayList every time this method gets called is quite performance costy. Simply iterating of the list and removing one by one causes less overhead.
- Adding the `toString` method to an interface does not do anything. You can not force a class to implement it as every class already has the default `Object` implementation.

Comment: Good points - thank you. Just one thing. `Receivable` and `Sendable` is used - in the `AbstractOperation` class